# Laravel @section and @show ignoring default content - why?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm learning how to code for Laravel after a long while working with simpler systems (mostly WP and raw PHP). For this I'm running the latest version and following the tutorial for Laravel 5 here:

https://tutorials.kode-blog.com/laravel-blade-template

However, I've ran into an issue. I'm on the **Extending the Master Layout** section, where it asks you to create a file on `/resources/views/page.blade.php` with the following content:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Page Title')

@section('sidebar')

<p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@endsection

@section('content')
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@endsection
```

Where the master layout, located in `/resources/views/layouts/master.blade.php`, contains this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>@yield('title')</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @section('sidebar')
            This is the master sidebar.
        @show

        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

According to the tutorial, the result when visiting `http://localhost/larashop/public/blade` after routing should be something among the lines of:

```
This is the master sidebar.

This is appended to the master sidebar.

This is my body content.
```

However, instead I'm getting:

```
This is appended to the master sidebar.

This is my body content.
```

The code is, for some reason, ignoring the `This is the master sidebar.` part of the code, or replacing it with the content from `@section('sidebar')`. I'll add that the code is being handled fine otherwise - the `<p></p>` and `<div></div>` from the master template appear where they should. It's just the default content for the sidebar doesn't. It does appear properly if I replace `@show` with `@yield('sidebar')`, but I'm really curious what is going on here and if for some reason I'm doing something wrong.

I believe there's likely a version difference, since the tutorial is for 5.0 and I'm on 5.4, but I can't find anything pointing me towards what the change is and why, and I want to know this before I move on ahead because I fear I'll find even more issues like this one.

I've already found a difference between the tutorial and my install, namely that `/app/Http/routes.php` is instead `/routes/web.php`, but that one was quite easy to find info about. For this one I can't find anything, so could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer. I dunno if this is because of a change between Laravel versions or if the tutorial is just wrong. The issue, as per this tutorial:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade

Is that `page.blade.php` was missing `@parent` inside the sidebar section. Thus, the file should read:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Page Title')

@section('sidebar')

    @parent

    <p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>

@endsection

@section('content')
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@endsection
```

With that, the section will be rendered first including the content on its parent section.

Answer (score 0):

In your page.blade.php

.

.
It should be @yield('sidebar') not @section('sidebar')

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on this? The @section('content') works fine, and I can't see why we'd use @endsection without a section opening. Is the tutorial wrong?

Comment: It could be that there's a slight mistake in the tutorial because i don't see how a person can make use of @section('content') without @endsection. visit [link](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017) for a good tutorial on laravel. Also check out laravel 5.4 blade documentation [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade)

Comment: Found out what the issue is. It was on page.blade.php, but the only issue was that said section was lacking `@parent`. Thanks for your links tho, I found the answer in them :D